# Error while using react-router-dom Router featues

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to react and have been struggling with the router for a crud application, attaching the app.js file and the console errors. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sunset-ycqo76?file=/src/components/AddUser.jsx)

```
import './App.css';

import AddUser from "./components/AddUser";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import CrudApp from "./components/CrudApp";
import AllUsers from "./components/AllUsers";
import{ Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
      <Routes>
      <Route path='/add'>
        <AddUser/> 
      </Route>
      
      <Route path='/all'>
        <AllUsers />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/'>
        <CrudApp />
      </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkA8P.png)

Comment: I don't see any issue with the router, but the routed component should be passed each `Route` component's `element` prop. What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? You can check by running `npm list react-router-dom`.

Comment: I am using react-router-dom 6.4.1. Moreover, I tried with the element prop as well, it gave out the same error, upon reading the documents, I tried this technique, gave the same error.

Comment: See if you can create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: Edited it into the original post. Kindly check. Thanks

Comment: The errors I see there in your sandbox are related to what I called out regarding the routed components. After moving them all to the `Route` component's `element` prop your sandbox runs without issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/error-while-using-react-router-dom-router-featues-f3ylmh